# android FATAL EXCEPTION java.lang.IllegalStateException: AssetManager has been finalized?

Tags: android

it wast when the app in background and i have no services in the app!!

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: AssetManager has been finalized!
   at android.content.res.AssetManager.setConfiguration(Native Method)
   at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.updateConfiguration(ResourcesImpl.java:429)
   at android.app.ResourcesManager.applyConfigurationToResourcesLocked(ResourcesManager.java:978)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:5224)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1767)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: Post your code where you have created an AssetManager variable.

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari I didn't use AssetManager at all!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ @Mauricio

Comment: happened once, the last line in stacktrace was "at android.content.res.AssetManager.getArrayStringResource(Native Method)". I got this crash while messing with Split-Screen option (available since Android 7) and restarted app with Instant run multiple times, so I think it's not a big deal. I don't think it will happen on production. This Instant run thing sometimes produces crashes on Android Studio during the development process.